# MySQL primary key on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I am creating a very simple database table from data provided to me in exel format, and I will be using 4 columns:

Date/time 
IP address
Hostname
Vulnerability identified

I usually get one exel sheet per day, with anything between 1000 - 3000 rows. The Date/time field consists of YYYYMMDDHHMM and can be duplicated a number of times, but should have a unique IP address against each same date/time column, e.g. 2012-08-26:16:01, 80.3.3.255, 2012-08-26:16:01, 192.168.0.1. Having reviewed some similar questions, would it be more efficient to generate a unique primary key per record, or join the date/time and IP column to create the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on at least two angles:

- on the `WHERE` criteria used later for selecting: If you plan to select by timestamp and IP independently, I suggest you create non-unique keys for those and a simple (maybe `AUTO_INCREMENT`) primary for each row.
- How you want to deal with it, if a duplicate timestamp/IP does occur: A unique or primary key would rule this out, while a separate key would happily coexist. It depends on your app requirements, which one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I like having an ID column for most/all tables, so I'd go that way.  Imagine extending your application with something like "notes" - how are you going to join them over to this table without an ID?

Also, I've had a few cases where automated loaders go crazy, and the ID is a helpful way of being able to identify the bad rows.

As @Eugen pointed out, just make a composite unique index on timestamp/IP.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience working with databases, dates make extremely poor fields for primary keys.  Every time I've encountered them, no matter how the application has been programmed there has always been something that bit you with dates.  Most often it's been "I mis-entered a date and now I want to change it but I can't without updating a dozen child tables" or "the database just duplicated my data because I corrected the date and the software re-submitted my report and it has no way of telling that it's a duplicate".

Additionally, you must remember that **dates are actually not guaranteed to be unique**.  As a trivial example, what happens when shifting the clock back for daylight savings time?  Suddenly you have a date where 1:00 am occurs twice, which means you already have a legitimate situation where date can collide for two instances.  Depending on your solution, you might need to be sure that the time zone is used or UTC is specified.  You could use a UNIX timestamp to help get around this issue, but even then you're relying on two different, unrelated computer systems to track time correctly and agree on reality.

Similarly, IP addresses need not be globally unique.  Private IP addressing and NAT can easily construct a scenario where two systems have the same IP address.  Indeed, you cannot use hostname, IP address, MAC address, or even BIOS serial number reliably and expect a guaranteed unique value unless you're a system administrator of all systems involved.  This is why system BIOS often have a GUID for the system (although I have seen instances where refurbished system boards will have an all zero GUID, so not even this is certain).

If you choose to use a composite key of both of these fields, then I suspect you'll have the worst of both worlds.

I understand you're working on a very small system and it's unlikely these issues will arise, but as a systems analyst I am immediately skeptical of the durability of a program that actually requires dates and IP addresses to be unique, particularly if the data is coming from multiple independent sources.

Comment: Thank you to all, this has been very useful and will no doubt save me some time in the future.